# Sharepoint Internet site that is like an intranet site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I want to build a Sharepoint site that in accessible from anywhere, not just our intranet.
I would therefore like the ability to have a login function, and once authenticated, the user would see what is common for people to see when accessing a classic intranet Sharepoint site. For instance, see documents based on role, check in/out docs, etc.
Is this possible?
All material I've read thus far seems to partition Internet Sharepoint sites and intranet Sharepoint sites. Is it possible to meld the two?

Comment: Sounds like a system administration question, not a programming one; serverfault, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sharepoint site which is published in internet can be used like a normal intranet site. The user will have to enter his/her userid and password to login. After successful login the internet site will act excatly as the intranet site.

If there are some part of the intranet which does not require authentication then you can grant anonymous access.

If you are looking for Dual Authentication then there are few steps which has to be done in the administration part. Few changes to `web.config` and in central administration will enable both Windows anf Forms authentication. you can add your own users who will be accessing the site from internet.

In this case we wil be extending the web application and will have different address for intranet and internet but the site content will be same.

Let me know your exact requirement and I can be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a few follow up questions. Question 1: If I am using Active Directory for our employees to login, may they log in via the internet? Question2: If I want non-employees to log in via the internet, do I need to have them entered in our AD, or how else would I enter users for authentication purposes in Sharepoint, just by manually entering them via the Central Admin tool, then the users are added to the current users (from AD)?
I'm not real clear by what you meant by Dual Authentication?

Comment: I just setup one last week. The site had both Internet and Intranet. Both AD login and custom login. Can yo drop me an email at shobankr[at]gmail.com ..... Its weekend ;-) i will reply you in a day or two. okay?